# Identifying Vague Language -- "individuals" vs "people"

Tags: word-choice, diction

I'm writing an essay, and in my intro I start with:

> For many individuals, value measures wealth and external beauty; for others, value measures more abstract elements such as love, intent, or heritage.

My question is, should "individuals" be replaced with "people" or something else?

Comment: It's writer's choice.  Either works.

Comment: You could even drop the word altogether and treat *many* as a substantive.